Free5GC/UERASIM - [error] TUN allocation failure [Open failure /dev/net/tun]
Please your kind support with this error, I0m trying to replicate testbed Free5GC, but after PDU session is established there show me an error TUN.
[2024-12-04 10:51:35.763] [nas] [info] Initial Registration is successful
[2024-12-04 10:51:35.763] [nas] [debug] Sending PDU Session Establishment Request
[2024-12-04 10:51:35.763] [nas] [debug] UAC access attempt is allowed for identity[0], category[MO_sig]
[2024-12-04 10:51:36.003] [nas] [debug] PDU Session Establishment Accept received
[2024-12-04 10:51:36.003] [nas] [info] PDU Session establishment is successful PSI[1]
[2024-12-04 10:51:36.003] [app] [error] TUN allocation failure [Open failure /dev/net/tun]
Im using UBUNTU 22.04 -kernel 5.15.0-126-generic
